# How to highlight a text in a online web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, highlight

I have a web application which retrieve information from web,
Taken data are shown in my web page. I have the string taken from the website and the link to that web site.

```
String = "won the Ethugalpura International Rating Chess Tournament"
url    = "http://www.island.lk/index.php?page_cat=article-details&page=article-details&code_title=15182"
```

When the user click on the string, I want to visit to relevant web site and display it with the highlighted text.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: u can't highlight text on other websites, unless those sites have your js files included (in case I understood the question correctly)

Answer (score 1):

So the new web site would be loaded and then on that new site the text ('String') would be highlighted on the new site?

I feel this is not possible for general usage.  You could certainly have a browser plug-in on your machine to do this but generally for other users, whose browser you do not control, one site cannot change the display of another site's content.  Thankfully.

Comment: is it possible for me to direct it to the browser's find text field? so I can easily highlight it?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Replacing text in the DOM](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-solved/), this will help you in highlighting the text by search, [Live DEMO](http://padolsey.github.com/findAndReplaceDOMText/demo.html)

Comment: Interesting link but seems to be all about changing the HTML of that target site which is not a practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly.

Technically, you could do it indirectly, by fetching the content of the external page, manipulating it (by searching for the string and putting it e.g. inside a `mark` element, and adding a CSS rule for highlighting that element), and then faking a link. That is, you would use an `a` element, looking like a link, but actually driven by an event handler that causes your modified document to be shown.

Naturally, you would need permission from the copyright holder of the external site.